# Why when caching queries are relationships not cached?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, caching, laravel-4

Throughout querying my database with the queries as the one below;

```
Model::with('first','second','third','fouth','fiveth')
->orderBy('title')
->remember(2,'domain.query')
->get()
```

The overall query gets cached etc, but why don't the relationships that I attach to the query. Would I have to do a join on the models etc to accomplish everything getting cached etc?

Queries made in Clockwork:

```
SELECT * FROM `first_table` WHERE `first_table`.`id` in ('2', '4', '3')
SELECT * FROM `second_table` WHERE `second_table`.`id` in ('2', '5', '1', '4')
SELECT * FROM `third_table` WHERE `third_table`.`id` in ('2', '5', '1', '4')
SELECT * FROM `fouth_table` WHERE `fouth_table`.`id` in ('2', '5', '1', '4')
SELECT * FROM `fiveth_table` WHERE `fiveth_table`.`id` in ('2', '5', '1', '4')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Why" is somewhat of a broad question, it is a design decision made by the framework author. The way to get around it, though it's not very pretty code, is to use eager load constraints:

`Model::with([
  'first' => function($q) { $q->remember(...); },
  'second' => ...
])->remember(...)->get();`

Comment: Thank you for the response. It does not look pretty at all. I shall look into it.